# how do I make an integer to roman algorithm in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to write an algorithm that converts integer numbers to roman numbers and supports any positive number in dart.

I can do this in Java using String builder and i tried to do it in dart but i failed.
so please if anyone could help me, that would be very much appreciated!

here is the java algorithm, maybe it would help:

```
public static int[] arabianRomanNumbers = new int[]{
        1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1
};
public static String[] romanNumbers = new String[]{
        "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"
};

public String intToRoman(int num) {
    if (num < 0) return "";
    else if (num == 0) return "nulla";

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int a = 0; a < arabianRomanNumbers.length; a++) {
        int times = num / arabianRomanNumbers[a]; // equals 1 only when arabianRomanNumbers[a] = num
        // executes n times where n is the number of times you have to add
        // the current roman number value to reach current num.
        builder.append(romanNumbers[a].repeat(times));
        num -= times * arabianRomanNumbers[a]; // subtract previous roman number value from num
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is called `StringBuffer` in Dart and does nearly the same but with a little different interface which you can read more about in the API documentation:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html

With this knowledge, I have converted your Java code into Dart:

```
const List<int> arabianRomanNumbers = [
  1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1
];

const List<String> romanNumbers = [
  "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"
];

String intToRoman(int input) {
  var num = input;

  if (num < 0) {
    return "";
  }
  else if (num == 0) {
    return "nulla";
  }

  final builder = StringBuffer();
  for (var a = 0; a < arabianRomanNumbers.length; a++) {
    final times = (num / arabianRomanNumbers[a]).truncate(); // equals 1 only when arabianRomanNumbers[a] = num
    // executes n times where n is the number of times you have to add
    // the current roman number value to reach current num.
    builder.write(romanNumbers[a] * times);
    num -= times * arabianRomanNumbers[a]; // subtract previous roman number value from num
  }

  return builder.toString();
}

void main() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    print('$i => ${intToRoman(i)}');
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use the [multiplication operator on strings](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/String/operator_multiply.html) and do not need a `repeat()` extension method. Writing `s * n` will repeat string `s` `n` times.

Comment: You are right... I must have been completely blind when I checked the documentation. I have updated my answer. :D